# How to return nil when adding two nil columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to perform a sum calculation. If it has 2 nil values then it needs to return nil but it is returning 0. How do I fix this issue?

This is what I am doing:

```
rating_size1=company_ratings.collect(&:r1).count
update_attributes(:attrib1 => company_ratings.sum("r1").to_f/rating_size1)
```

If `r1` is nil then the calculation should return nil. How can I do this?

Comment: What are you saying ?

Comment: I am try to show a nil or a blank space when I am adding two nil columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not change it to

```
update_attributes(:attrib1 => (company_ratings.sum("r1").to_f/rating_size1 if company_ratings.any?))
```

or

```
update_attributes(:attrib1 => (company_ratings.sum("r1").to_f/rating_size1 if rating_size1 > 0))
```

Comment: no it is still showing '0' in the out put I wanted to show it as a black or nil in the display

Comment: can you add the additional braces, then the whole should definitely evaluate to {:attrib1 => nil}

Comment: I found another issue it is taking nil all the time if I have a value also.

Comment: I don't understand, as {x: (6/3 if false)} => {:x=>nil}
and {x: (6/3 if true)} => {:x=>2}

Comment: Let if I have a= 3 and b=3 count=2 then p1 => a+b/count  then p1= 2 but if a=nil and b=nil and count=nil then p1 => a+b/count that should be nil i.e p1= nil and if a= nil and b=3 count=1 then p1=> a+b/count that is p1= 3  this is want the conditions I am trying to do.

Comment: I finally think I understand what you want. Just try company_ratings.average(:r1). This ignores all nil values, and even returns nil in case of no values at all.

Comment: Reason is average returns nil in case of no data at all, whereas sum returns 0 in case of no data at all. Dividing 0 by any number stays 0.